# Rails Devise - Logout error ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Devise and trying to build the Logout link to logout of the user session.

I have included jquery-ujs file in the template and its loading correctly.

This is my Logout link

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

But when i click the link i am getting the following error

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken at /users/sign_out

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the authenticity token, then provide it.

```
<%= form_tag destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit 'Sign Out' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i need to do a form tag for signout ?? this is insane

Comment: Possibly.. but your error message is saying that your need an authenticity token.  Can you try it and see what happens?

Comment: It seems that the accepted answer is not the actual answer, it was the missing `csrf_meta_tags` that resolved the issue.